# Goroutine didn't run as expected

Tags: go

I'm still learning Go and was doing the exercise of a web crawler as linked [here](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10). The main part I implemented is as follows. (Other parts remain the same and can be found in the link.)

```golang
// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    cache.Set(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)

    for _, u := range urls {
        if cache.Get(u) == false {
            fmt.Println("Next:", u)
            Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher) // I want to parallelize this
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}

type SafeCache struct {
    v   map[string]bool
    mux sync.Mutex
}

func (c *SafeCache) Set(key string) {
    c.mux.Lock()
    c.v[key] = true
    c.mux.Unlock()
}

func (c *SafeCache) Get(key string) bool {
    return c.v[key]
}

var cache SafeCache = SafeCache{v: make(map[string]bool)}
```

When I ran the code above, the result was expected:

```
found: https://golang.org/ "The Go Programming Language"
Next: https://golang.org/pkg/
found: https://golang.org/pkg/ "Packages"
Next: https://golang.org/cmd/
not found: https://golang.org/cmd/
Next: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/
found: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/ "Package fmt"
Next: https://golang.org/pkg/os/
found: https://golang.org/pkg/os/ "Package os"
```

However, when I tried to parallelize the crawler (on the line with a comment in the program above) by changing `Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)` to `go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)`, the results were not as I expected:

```
found: https://golang.org/ "The Go Programming Language"
Next: https://golang.org/pkg/
Next: https://golang.org/cmd/
```

I thought directly adding a `go` keyword is as straightforward as it seems, but I'm not not sure what went wrong and confused on how I should best approach this problem. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you add the `go Crawl` inside the `Crawl` function?, most likely your program is exiting before the crawlers finish doing their work. Take a look at [WaitGroup](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups)

Comment: @Niwatori the answer you checked is blatantly wrong: it has a race condition (if you add goroutines like you did in your code) (not too hard to fix, but would require some effort)

Comment: @zerkms Could you elaborate a little bit? I'm guessing the variable u is causing a race condition but not quite sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is most likely exiting before the crawlers finish doing their work. One approach would be for the `Crawl` to have a `WaitGroup` where it waits for all of it's sub crawlers to finish. For example

```
import "sync"

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, *wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer func() {
        // If the crawler was given a wait group, signal that it's finished
        if wg != nil {
            wg.Done()
        }
    }()

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    _, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    cache.Set(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)

    var crawlers sync.WaitGroup
    for _, u := range urls {
        if cache.Get(u) == false {
            fmt.Println("Next:", u)
            crawlers.Add(1)
            go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, &crawlers)
        }
    }
    crawlers.Wait() // Waits for its sub-crawlers to finish

    return 
}

func main() {
   // The root does not need a WaitGroup
   Crawl("http://example.com/index.html", 4, nil)
}
```

Comment: What's the point to use `WaitGroup` in a non-concurrent code? If you remove it nothing would change.

Comment: I assume it should be `go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, &crawlers)` in the loop but it indeed solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Niwatori if you add `go` there then this code is prone to a race condition. So it really does not "solve the problem".

Comment: @Tristian: now after you modified your code - it's prone to race condition around concurrent `wg.Add` and `wg.Wait` calls.

Comment: @zerkms Yes I missed adding the `go` statement inside the loop and I also fixed the `defer` statement. I was on a mobile so not much of room to juggle the text. The `wg.Add` is called in the `crawlers` wait group not in the `wg` that is passed by the parent caller. The `crawlers` will not block if there are no crawlers to wait for.

Comment: I was wrong, there is no race condition here, my apologies.

Comment: I guess if you do `wg.Add` inside the go statement then it should cause a race condition, no?

Comment: Not as far as I understand it, the variable `crawlers` (which is a WaitGroup) is the only one that gets `Add` called on, that same wait group is only waited for after all of the crawlers have been added, there's no modification after that. The `crawlers` var will be passed to each `Crawl` call and the `Crawl` function will call `wg.Done` once it finishes. There are 2 wait groups one that is passed in by the parent by reference `wg` and `crawlers` which is created by the `Crawl` function to wait for it's sub crawlers.